# Filter wordpress posts by custom date range input

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a custom post type 'lesson' and it has a custom field attached to it called 'date of lesson. The date range and query works fine, however I need to allow the user to input the date range themselves and then have the list update (e.g. for this month, or for this week) and can't seem to work out how to allow them to input dates and then update the query with this. For reference, the query from taxonomy-subject.php:

```
$args = array(

       'meta_key' => 'date_of_lesson', // The meta key to sort on
       'orderby' => 'meta_value',
       'order' => 'ASC',
       'posts_per_page' => -1,
       'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key' => 'date_of_lesson',
        'value' => array($startdate, $enddate),
        'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
        'type' => 'DATE'
    )
)
```

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: Am I missing something or are you asking how to make a form with two date selectors?

Comment: I'm struggling with taking their inputs and updating the query, as say I'm viewing the 'Subject' tax-page, with all posts from 2015, and the user wants to narrow this to one month, and then maybe another month after, I don't know how to update the query to narrow it down, might be me being narrow minded, but regardless I'm stuck

Comment: Can you provide some more code then and elaborate on "their inputs" - show us what you get / have and we can help you get it in the right format for you're query to work. The more you give to us the more you will get back :) So if you use a form to get the dates from a user, show us that form.

Comment: Sorry, not the best with this, basically, tried a html form with two inputs for start and end date (won't show code as it's just a form), tried to do that when 'Submit' is pressed, the posts will update and only those between the date range will be shown. Not sure how to change the query after the initial page load etc., like I say, I'm not really anywhere 'good' with this, other than that the query works fine first time if I apply dates to the variables before the loop. Thanks for any help.

Comment: You need to keep the form on the page and make sure the date fields retain the submitted values (value="" etc...) then the user can adjust the dates and submit again. Hope that is what you mean. The page will re-load again as you have to call the query code again. So each time you / they change the dates the page has to load again. Unless you use ajax but thats a whole different kettle of fish :)

Comment: Thanks so much Simon, that helped to get it done! Have it all working perfectly now, no problems whatsoever! If I could, I would mark that as the solution.

Comment: I will write up an answer for you summarising what I put

Comment: please accept my answer if that is what helped you, cheers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you need to set up a form on the page that displays your data with your from and to dates, using something like jQuery date picker makes life easier and keeps them to one field.

When submitted, get the values and check the format of them and make sure it is YYYY-MM-DD as per https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query. You might need to use http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php and then http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php if you don't have your date in the right format.

When the form is posted, be sure to keep the posted date values in your form (value="" etc...), so the user can easily adjust what they are looking at and then submit the form again to make any adjustments.

Answer (score 0):

You have to just convert the date that the user is giving in **strtotime** format and then change it to '***yyyy-mm-dd***'(2016-05-24) format and pass in this query. If this format is not passed the query will return empty result.

User Selected Input should be changed as per this format below as start date and end date.

```
$start = '2011-11-31';
$end = '2011-10-01';
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'YOUR-POST-TYPE',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'meta_key' => 'date_of_lesson',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'date_of_lesson',
            'value' => array($start, $end),
            'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
            'type' => 'DATE'
        )
    )
);
// Make the query
$events_query = new WP_query();
$events_query->query($args);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, as mentioned above, the problem wasn't in the actual use of the query, that works fine in the same way you gave, it's how to update the query with a user's inputs (from either two Jquery datepicker or via two HTML input boxes within the correct format)?

Comment: Mark my response Response as Useful bro. Since as per your question the response by me was right know.

Comment: I did say I was struggling with using their inputs, not the query, or is it a case of everytime they input dates and the new input is saved to the variable, the page will update with the new posts from the query automatically?

Comment: Hi Bro, Can you please explain what is the meaning for this as you have mentioned in the question : "  however I need to allow the user to input the date range themselves and then have the list update (e.g. for this month, or for this week) and can't seem to work out how to allow them to input dates and then update the query with this." - You have asked how to input the dates and update the Query..